# What are valid date-time separators in RFC3339 strings?

Tags: rfc3339

I'm quite confused as to what's allowed as the time separator/designator in the [RFC3339 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339). By time separator I mean the sequence of characters that draw the line between date and time.

The standard states [in section 5.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) different things that are unclear or conflicting. First of all, it says that the production rule for a full datetime is this:

```
date-time = full-date "T" full-time
```

Meaning that the delimiter between the date and the time is an uppercase `T`. Right after comes this:

```
  NOTE: Per [ABNF] and ISO8601, the "T" and "Z" characters in this
  syntax may alternatively be lower case "t" or "z" respectively
```

Meaning the upper case `T` *may* be a lower case `t`. It conflicts with the ABNF, but OK, it stills sounds to me within the realm of reasonable. Then the following is stated

```
  NOTE: ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T".
  Applications using this syntax may choose, for the sake of
  readability, to specify a full-date and full-time separated by
  (say) a space character.
```

Which is very confusing. Does this allow not only a space character but anything? which is what this `say` implies. Or does it by `this syntax` refer to ISO8601 and unnecessarily describes a detail of that other standard?

In other words, are the following valid RFC3339 strings?

- `2020-09-07 20:26:03.623359300+02:00`
- `2020-09-07hey johnny20:26:03.623359300+02:00`
- `2020-09-0720:26:03.623359300+02:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: `T` (or `t` as discouraged alternative).

After reading on this as much as I could, it turns out the time separator must be a `T` or `t`. What has made think this way is first of all [this thread in the GNU lists](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2010-05/msg00029.html) where F. Alexander Njemz contacted the authors of RFC3339 Graham Klyne and Chris Newman asking if `T` is mandatory and got this response from Mr. Klyne:

> In short: "yes"
>
> Per section 5.5, the intent in this draft was to specify a timestamp format using
> elements from and compatible with 8601, but eliminating as far as
> reasonable any variations that could make timestamp data harder to
> process. This includes making the 'T' mandatory in date+time values.
>
> #g

Just for clarity's sake, this is stated in the [section 5.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.5):

> Simplicity is achieved by making most fields and punctuation
> mandatory.

This clearly clashes with a non-mandatory `T` and strongly makes me think that the `this syntax` in that problematic passage refers to ISO8601 and not RFC3339.

For those who want to read more, here are some links regarding the confusion created by this specific point:

- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2006-05/msg00014.html
- http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/InvalidRFC3339Date.html
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid5783

Plus of course divergent implementations. For instance, the developers of GNU Date chose to use a space character:

```
$ date --rfc-3339=seconds
2020-09-14 14:53:51+02:00
```

Answer (score -1):

> Meaning the upper case `T` *may* be a lower case `t`. It conflicts with the ABNF, [...]

It does not. See [2.3  Terminal Values](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234#section-2.3) of RFC 2234:

> ```
> Literal text strings are interpreted as a concatenated set of
> printable characters.
>
>    NOTE:     ABNF strings are case-insensitive and
>              the character set for these strings is us-ascii.
> ```

So it is allowed to use `t` here.

> ```
>   NOTE: ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T".
>   Applications using this syntax may choose, for the sake of
>   readability, to specify a full-date and full-time separated by
>   (say) a space character.
> ```
>
> Which is very confusing. Does this allow not only a space character
> but anything?

This "deviation" is used for **readability** to the user when displayed. So when the value is displayed to the user in some kind, it can be displayed as:

- 2020-09-07 20:26:03.623359300+02:00
- 2020-09-07, 20:26:03.623359300+02:00

That way it might be easier for the user to see the clear space between the date and time, so they don't have to look for the `T` or `t` character to find the separation. It is indeed a vague sentence as it basically mean the application can do anything.

To answer your question: These listed date formats are not valid according to RFC 3339.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't know that the ABNF was case insensitive. As to the "readability", I tried to understand it that way, but dropped it because how the date-time is to be displayed to a user has nothing to do with how to unequivocally exchange date-times, which is (I guess) the purpose of the RFC.